# Rails 4 Devise nested form can't mass-assign protected attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, nested-attributes

I have a devise model that has a nested form (supp_form is the nested object) on sign up. When I submit the form I am getting the following error:

```
WARNING: Can't mass-assign protected attributes for Business: supp_form_attributes, terms_of_service
app/controllers/businesses/registrations_controller.rb:11:in `create'
```

I am using the nested_form gem and it seems as if my form is passing field data through to the console. My parameters after submit look like the following:

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"XXX", "business"=>{"type"=>"Business", "supp_form_attributes"=>{"title"=>"mr.", "first_name"=>"jane", "last_name"=>"doe", "mobile_phone_number"=>"94034903", "loan_agreement_authorization"=>"1", "work_phone_number"=>"49034903", "business_industry"=>"Natural Resources and Mining", "legal_structure"=>"Sole Proprietorship", "employee_count"=>"5 to 10", "years_in_business"=>"5+ years", "business_address"=>"72 pentland rd", "business_city"=>"Waterdown", "business_postal_code"=>"l0r2h5", "business_province"=>"ON"}
```

**business.rb**

```
class Business < User
  # Associations
  has_one :supp_form
  has_many :loan_applications
  has_many :transactions

  # Nested attributes
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :supp_form, :loan_applications

  # After save action
  after_save :create_account

  # Validations
  validates_acceptance_of :terms_of_service
  validate :terms_of_service, presence: true 
end
```

**supp_form.rb**

```
class SuppForm < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Associations
  belongs_to :business

  # Validations
  validates_acceptance_of :terms
  validates :business_id, :first_name, :last_name, :work_phone_number, :business_address, :business_postal_code, :business_city, presence: true
end
```

**registraionts_controller.rb**

```
class Businesses::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  before_filter :update_sanitized_params

  def new
    build_resource({})
    resource.build_supp_form
    respond_with self.resource
  end

  def create
    super
    resource.update_attribute(:railsid, '%010d' % rand(10 ** 10))
  end

  private

    def update_sanitized_params
      devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) {|u| u.permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation, :type, :confirmed_at, :business_name, :terms, :railsid, :terms_of_service,
                                                              supp_form_attributes: [:business_id, :title, :loan_agreement_authorization, :first_name, 
                                                                                    :last_name, :work_phone_number, :business_address, :business_postal_code, 
                                                                                    :business_city, :business_name, :years_in_business, :legal_structure, 
                                                                                    :business_industry, :employee_count, :mobile_phone_number, :business_province])}
    end

    def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
      business_root_path
    end

end
```

**supp_forms_controller.rb**

```
class SuppFormsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!

  def new
    @suppform = SuppForm.new(supp_form_params)
  end

  def create
    @suppform = SuppForm.create(supp_form_params)
  end 

  private

    def supp_form_params
      params.require(:supp_form).permit(:business_id, :title, :loan_agreement_authorization, :first_name, 
                                                                                :last_name, :work_phone_number, :business_address, :business_postal_code, 
                                                                                :business_city, :business_name, :years_in_business, :legal_structure, 
                                                                                :business_industry, :employee_count, :mobile_phone_number, :business_province)
    end
end
```

Comment: check which controller is handling the response, you don't need to post the code of all controllers, just the one that is showing in server console, it should be near the warning and parameters.

Comment: In the console response it points to: app/controllers/businesses/registrations_controller.rb:11:in `create'. I'll post that in the question as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using Rails 4 with strong parameters. And you get an error triggered by the protected_attributes gem (or default rails 3 app).

With strong_parameters on place you can remove safety the protected_attributes gem. And remove the configuration if you have it (config.active_record.whitelist_attributes).

Comment: I commented out the whitelist_attributes config line in the application config file, then removed the protected attributes gem. I had to change some code in my other models (that used attr_accessible) but everything seems to be fine now. Thank you!